# How to pass an array without a static order? C language

Tags: c, arrays

I need to calculate the determinant of an array of order n in C language. But I have the following error:

> [Error] expected ')' before ',' token

How to pass an array without a static order?
Here is the declaration:

```
double determinante(int matriz[][], int order)
```

and it's the function that calls the function above:

```
    int cofator(int order, int matriz[order][order], int linha, int coluna);
double determinante(int order, int matriz[order][order]);

int cofator(int order, int matriz[order][order], int linha, int coluna)
{
    int submatriz[C][C];
    int n = ordem - 1;
    int i, j;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ordem; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ordem; j++) {
            if (i != linha && j != coluna) {
                submatriz[x][y] = matriz[i][j];
                y++;
                if (y >= n) {
                    x++;
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pow(-1.0, linha + coluna) * determinante(submatriz, n);
}

double determinante(int order, int matriz[order][order]) {
    int det = 0.0, j;
    if (ordem == 1) {
        det = matriz[0][0];
    } else {
        for (j = 0; j < ordem; j++) {
            det = det + matriz[0][j] * cofator(matriz, ordem, 0, j);
        }
    }
    printf("O determinante da matriz eh %d \n", det);
    return det;
}

bool ehConvergente(int order, int matriz[order][order]) {
    int n = 1, value = 1;
    int submatriz[ordem][ordem];
    do {
        for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<= n; j++) {
                submatriz[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
            }
        }

        if(determinante(n, submatriz) == 0)
            value++;

        for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<= n; j++) {
                submatriz[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        n++;
    } while(n == ordem);

    if(value > 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It kind of depends on how you declare the array initially...

Comment: `int[][]` isn't a valid type in C, nor a valid function parameter declaration.

Comment: I edited my question, now you can see how I declare the array initially (in in other function that calls)

Comment: You've got both `order` and `ordem` appearing in the revised code.  Are they meant to be the same or are they meant to be different?  If different, how is `ordem` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use C99, or a C11 compiler that does not define `__STDC_NO_VLA__`, you can use:

```
double determinante(size_t rows, size_t cols, int array[rows][cols])
{
    …
}
```

You could omit `rows` from the array; declaration; you can’t omit `cols`.  You could use other integer types than `size_t` if you wish.

Comment: I edited my code, add the config C99 but, I'm using Dev C++. The following error, appears:  [Warning] command line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

Comment: You're compiling your "C" code as C++ — you wouldn't get the message if you were compiling as C.